# How do i retain original columns after groupby without agg functions?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to retain the original columns after i do a groupby that is no count, no mean i want just the original columns populated with the columns.

```
grouped=df.sort_values(['Date-UTC'],ascending=True).groupby(['Buyer','Seller'])
```

I am trying to get the selleres for each buyer whilst at the same time trying to retain the columns so i can still see the company the seller belongs to and all other attributes.

it seems when i do:

```
grouped.first()
```

it has an output i'd like but how do i get ALL of the table in this format?

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to do. why can't you just use `agg` functions?

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 after grouping by two fields i'm trying to retain all other columns, i do not want counts in the columns or means.

Comment: But why not just use agg?

Comment: @Maths12 How about just sorting ['Buyer','Seller','Date-UTC']? I mean I'm not 100% sure what your intended output looks like though. Groupby would allow you to perform some aggregated operation on the dataframe slices of unique Buyer/Seller combos. It seems like you just want them sorted.